# What is PRE Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I installed a version of Visual Studio 2015 in May this year. The version had PRE in the icon. Yesterday I upgraded the Visual Studio with the latest from the MSDN website. I still see the PRE in the icon.

What does this PRE mean?

[image]

Comment: What does the about screen of Visual Studio say about the version number? It looks like you have an only build, but it could also be an installer bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options

1. You downloaded and installed the RC version from MSDN, currently both versions are listed in the download section.
2. There is a bug in the installer that didn't update the icon of the shortcut. Try unpinning and re-pinning it to the taskbar to force an icon update.

You should see the following version in the About screen of Visual Studio:

[image: Visual Studio about page version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL]

Answer (score 0):

"Pre"-Release, you couldn't have downloaded the release version from MSDN.

Comment: The second is not the case, the "pre" indicator is for showing that this is not yet the RTM version.

Comment: It does not show the PRE anymore on my laptop after I reinstalled the Visual Studio from 2015 from the MSDN website. It might have been a deployment issue where the icons were of the preview version.

Answer (score 0):

This is RC (Release Candidate) version of Visual Studio 2015.Lucky you , Visual Studio RTM is released yesterday and you can download it officially.